# How do prevent Newtonsoft.JSON from reusing default values when setting values during deserialization

Tags: json.net

This is an odd case, but it's a pattern we use a lot to deal with SQL back ends when we don't want to break the data into a separate table.

The problem here is, on deserialization, `MyList` has two items in it, instead of one. The root of the problem is that when the deserializer gets to the `MyList` property it reuses the existing value instead of resetting the property.

Here is the code:

```cs
public class Jason
{
    public object FromJSON(string json, Type t)
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings s = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        s.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());
        s.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, t, s);
    }

    public string ToJSON(object o)
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings s = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        s.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());
        s.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o, s);
    }

    public string MyListString
    {
        get { return ToJSON(_MyList); }
        set { _MyList = (List<string>)FromJSON(value, typeof(List<string>)); }
    }

    private List<string> _MyList = new List<string>();
    public List<string> MyList
    {
        get { return _MyList; }
        set { _MyList = value; }
    }

}

[TestFixture]
public class JasonTests : TestFixtureBase
{
    [Test]
    public void Jason()
    {
        Jason j = new Jason();
        j.MyList.Add("hello");

        string json = j.ToJSON(j);

        Jason j2 = (Jason)j.FromJSON(json, typeof(Jason));

        Assert.AreEqual(j.MyList.Count, j2.MyList.Count);
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Property getter invoked during deserialization instead of setter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553459/property-getter-invoked-during-deserialization-instead-of-setter)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after examining the source code and trying to fix what I thought was a bug, then googling around to see if anyone else had this problem it occurred to me that there might be a setting, and sure enough, there was.  Here is the fixed code:

```cs
public class Jason
{
    public object FromJSON(string json, Type t)
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings s = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        s.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());
        s.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        s.ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace; // without this, you end up with duplicates.
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, t, s);
    }

    public string ToJSON(object o)
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings s = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        s.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());
        s.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        s.ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace; // without this, you end up with duplicates.
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o, s);
    }

    public string MyListString
    {
        get { return ToJSON(_MyList); }
        set { _MyList = (List<string>)FromJSON(value, typeof(List<string>)); }
    }

    private List<string> _MyList = new List<string>();
    public List<string> MyList
    {
        get { return _MyList; }
        set { _MyList = value; }
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class JasonTests : TestFixtureBase
{

    [Test]
    public void Jason()
    {
        Jason j = new Jason();
        j.MyList.Add("hello");

        string json = j.ToJSON(j);

        Jason j2 = (Jason)j.FromJSON(json, typeof(Jason));

        Assert.AreEqual(j.MyList.Count, j2.MyList.Count);

    }
 }
```