# Json deserialization issues with Tuples?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, javascriptserializer

I have a class I use for configuration that holds a 3 tuple of all integers.

```
public class Configuration
{
    public List<Tuple<int, int, int>> MyThreeTuple { get; set; }

    public Configuration()
    {
        MyThreeTuple = new List<Tuple<int, int, int>>();
        MyThreeTuple.Add(new Tuple<int, int, int>(-100, 20, 501));
        MyThreeTuple.Add(new Tuple<int, int, int>(100, 20, 864));
        MyThreeTuple.Add(new Tuple<int, int, int>(500, 20, 1286));
    }
}
```

This class is serialized into Json with `System.Web.Script.Serialization` as such

```
JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
String configJson = jsonSerializer.Serialize(config);
File.WriteAllText(configPath, configJson);
```

and then deserialized when the application is launched

```
String configJson = File.ReadAllText(configPath);
JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
object jsonObject = jsonSerializer.Deserialize(configJson, typeof(ApplicationConfiguration));
appConfig = (Configuration)jsonObject;
```

My issue is that whenever I go to deserialize the Json an exception is thrown

```
System.MissingMethodException in System.Web.Extensions.dll
```

With the message

```
No parameterless constructor defined for type of `System.Tuple`3 ....
```

This is what the produced Json for the tuple looks like

```
"MyThreeTuple":
 [
    {"Item1":-100,"Item2":20,"Item3":501},
    {"Item1":100,"Item2":20,"Item3":864},
    {"Item1":500,"Item2":20,"Item3":1286}
 ]
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**

As other have suggested I tried out JSon.NET and it seems to work to deserialize the json. Though I have found an odd quirk.

So the constructor for my `Configuration` class fills in default values for the configuration. Specifically what is given in the code above. I have found that I can serialize the configuration with different values, but when deserialized, the default values are also loaded to the `List<Tuple<>>`.

I assume the Json.Net gets around the issue of `Tuple` not having a parameterless constructor by first instantiating `Configuration` and then setting its values.

It seems to be instantiating the class, then `List.Add`ing the `Tuple`s it finds in the json to the list. Instead of clearing the list then adding what it finds.

Is there an option in JSon.Net to solve this issue?

Comment: Systen.Tuple doesn't have parameterless constructor at all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739348/why-i-could-not-serialize-a-tuple-in-c read this Question and answers

Comment: If you are willing to use JSON.net, it [supports Tuple serialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101115/how-does-a-tuple-serialize-to-and-deserialize-from-json).

Comment: I've made an edit above about the usage of JSon.Net.

Comment: check my  answer I fixed this with  a simple  [JsonIgnore]

Comment: @KDecker Regarding your edit, set `ObjectCreationHandling` to `Replace`.  See [Json.Net calls property getter during deserialization of list, resulting in duplicate items](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25553459/10263).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you  got this error because JavascriptSerializer requires a public parameter-less constructor  which is not the case for Tuple because it's an `immutable`

take a look  here  http://json.codeplex.com/  for full comparison  between javascriptserializer and json.net

Even microsoft states in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)

*Json.NET should be used serialization and deserialization. Provides serialization and deserialization functionality for AJAX-enabled applications.*

here an example on how you  can easily use `JsonConvert` to achieve this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApplication25
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            string configJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(configuration);
            File.WriteAllText(configPath, configJson);
            //Deserialize the  content after you read your file in string 

             var   configurationDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Configuration>(configJson); 



        }
    }
}

public class Configuration
{
     [JsonIgnore]
    public List<Tuple<int, int, int>> MyThreeTuple { get; set; }

    public Configuration()
    {
        MyThreeTuple = new List<Tuple<int, int, int>>();
        MyThreeTuple.Add(new Tuple<int, int, int>(-100, 20, 501));
        MyThreeTuple.Add(new Tuple<int, int, int>(100, 20, 864));
        MyThreeTuple.Add(new Tuple<int, int, int>(500, 20, 1286));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example's testing is not meaningful. Since `new Configuration()` already adds the three tuples, your test can't distinguish between `MyThreeTuple` not being serialised at all, `MyThreeTuple` being serialised but ignored during deserialisation, and `MyThreeTuple` being serialised and deserialised correctly. (But even if your testing isn't right, the result could still well be.)

Comment: @hvd you have right but fixed with a simple  [JsonIgnore]

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve using Newtonsoft.Json

1. Install Newtonsoft.Json using nuget (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

Serialize :

```
var myObject = new Configuration();
var objString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);
```

Deserialize:

```
 var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(objString, typeof(Configuration));
```

Or

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Configuration>(objString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, I wanted to point out that it *is* possible to deserialize a `Tuple<int, int, int>` using the `JavaScriptSerializer`, but you need a `JavaScriptConverter` to do it.  The converter handles instantiating the `Tuple` from the values in the JSON, thus avoiding the exception.

```
class ThreeTupleConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get { return new List<Type> { typeof(Tuple<int, int, int>) }; }
    }

    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        int item1 = (int)dictionary["Item1"];
        int item2 = (int)dictionary["Item2"];
        int item3 = (int)dictionary["Item3"];
        return new Tuple<int, int, int>(item1, item2, item3);
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use the converter, you must register it with the serializer like this:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.RegisterConverters(new List<JavaScriptConverter> { new ThreeTupleConverter() });
```

Then deserialize as you normally would, and it should work fine:

```
string configJson = @"
{
    ""MyThreeTuple"":
    [
        { ""Item1"": -100, ""Item2"": 20, ""Item3"": 501 },
        { ""Item1"": 100, ""Item2"": 20, ""Item3"": 864 },
        { ""Item1"": 500, ""Item2"": 20, ""Item3"": 1286 }
    ]
}";

var config = serializer.Deserialize<Configuration>(configJson);

foreach (var tuple in config.MyThreeTuple)
{
    Console.WriteLine("(" + tuple.Item1 + ", " + tuple.Item2 + ", " + tuple.Item3 + ")");
}
```

Output:

```
(-100, 20, 501)
(100, 20, 864)
(500, 20, 1286)
```